# How to change text on one link by clicking on two different links?

Tags: jquery

So i have this demo :https://jsfiddle.net/gec5djan/ but i dont know how on one click change both text values. Any suggestion?

```
   $('h3.panel-title a').click(function(){
      if($(this).hasClass('collapsed')) {
          $(this).html('CLOSE <span class="arrow_right2"></span>');
    }
     else{
         $(this).html('SHOW ALL BOATS <span class="green-arrow-up"></span>');
    }
  });
```

Comment: What values `both values`?

Comment: i mean to change text ... to be same on both links

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of calling `$(this).html()` inside the click function you can use the selector that covers both items, like `$('h3.panel-title a')`:

HTML:

```
<h3 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#nested1" href="#nested-collapseOne">
            SHOW ALL BOATS <span class="arrow_right2"></span>
    </a>
</h3>

<h3 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#nested1" href="#nested-collapseOne">
            SHOW ALL BOATS <span class="arrow_right2"></span>
    </a>
</h3>
```

JavaScript:

```
   $('h3.panel-title a').click(function(){
      if($('h3.panel-title a').hasClass('collapsed')) {
          $('h3.panel-title a').html('CLOSE <span class="arrow_right2"></span>');
    }
     else{
         $('h3.panel-title a').html('SHOW ALL BOATS <span class="green-arrow-up"></span>');
    }
  });
```

All that being said, I would revisit the overall logic of your application. This doesn't seem to me like the cleanest way to enable this functionality though I don't know exactly what you're trying to ultimately do.

Comment: I have two buttons but they have same function ... to display some text....and without $(this) it will replace all h3.panel-title a and i want only specific

Comment: Then use `$('h3.panel-title a.collapsed')` as your selector (both for the click() function and also inside your function). Your final JavaScript would then be shorter: `$('h3.panel-title a.collapsed').click(function(){
 $('h3.panel-title a').html('CLOSE <span class="arrow_right2"></span>');
});`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if that's what you want :

```
   $('h3.panel-title a').click(function(){
      if($(this).hasClass('collapsed')) {
          $('h3.panel-title a').html('CLOSE <span class="arrow_right2"> </span>');
   }
   else{
     $('h3.panel-title a').html('SHOW ALL BOATS <span class="green-arrow-up"></span>');
   }
   });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gec5djan/1/

Answer (score 1):

I'm too late. Again.. 
This answer using short-circuit solution.

```
$('h3.panel-title a').click(function(){
    var html = $('h3.panel-title a').hasClass('collapsed')   
        ? 'CLOSE <span class="arrow_right2"></span>' 
        : 'SHOW ALL BOATS <span class="green-arrow-up"></span>'
    $('h3.panel-title a').html( html );
});
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gec5djan/2/)